# Cardinality of subsets of $\omega$ missed by the first $\omega$th terms in a $\diamondsuit$-sequence

Tags: set-theory

Assume $\diamondsuit$ and let $\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha < \omega_1}$ be a $\diamondsuit$-sequence.

What is the cardinality of the set $Y = \{X \subset \omega : \forall 0< \alpha < \omega, X \cap \alpha \neq S_\alpha\}$. I believe it's clear that this set is not empty. We can construct an $X \subset \omega$ by simply adding or removing the highest ordinal in the term $S_n$ for $n < \omega$. It feels like $|Y| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, but I am unable to formalize it.

Comment: It is completely irrelevant that you have a $\diamondsuit$-sequence.  You might as well just say you have an arbitrary sequence $(S_n)_{n<\omega}$ with $S_n\subseteq n$ for each $n$.

Comment: Also I guess in the definition of $Y$ you want to restrict to $\alpha\neq 0$?  Since $X\cap 0$ is always going to be equal to $S_0$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for $Y$ to have just one element.  For instance, suppose $S_n=\{n-1\}$ for each $n>0$.  Then the only element of $Y$ is the empty set, since if $X$ is nonempty then $X\cap n=S_n$ if $n-1$ is the least element of $X$.

(On the other hand, it's also of course possible for $Y$ to have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, for instance if every $S_n$ is empty so $Y$ is the set of all $X$ that contain $0$.)

Comment: You have no idea how thankful I am for your response. The fact that there are cases when $|Y| =1$ went right over my head. This fixes everything for me.